# Set default options of DxDataGrid

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular, dx-data-grid

I have an angular application which has a lot of components using DxDataGrid, all of them have the same default options. Is it possible to set the default options somewhere at any settings file or something similar?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you have already written?

Comment: Answer is down. I can accept the answer in 2 days..

Comment: cool! glad to hear that you solved it. but anyway to keep stackoverflow.com useful, we try to post self contained question & answers, not to make people follow links to get the answer / question, read everything right here: for questions include [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and for answers, quote and copy paste here.

Comment: Sorry! Updated answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dxDataGrid.defaultOptions method to set default configuration options for all DataGrid widgets. This method is static and you can call it in a constructor of the main component.

```
export class AppModule {  
  constructor() {  
    DataGrid.defaultOptions({  
      options: {  
        showRowLines: true,  
        showColumnLines: false,  
        rowAlternationEnabled: false,  
        focusedRowEnabled: true,  
        allowColumnResizing: true,  
        noDataText: "",  
        scrolling: {  
          mode: "virtual"  
        },  
        sorting: {  
          mode: "single"  
        },  
        loadPanel: {  
          enabled: false  
        }
      }  
    });  
  }  
}
```

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T738119/datagrid-how-to-define-default-configuration-options-for-angular-components

Answered in this question from DevExtreme support